# Impersonate a thread with user's filtered token

Tags: windows, winapi, uac, local-security-authority

I'm writing an app that is a sort of a custom corporate setup.
This app does a lot of tasks, some of them requires elevation.

I included a manifest so that when the app start the UAC ask user for elevation.

One of these task is mapping some network drives (with `WNetAddConnection`) to a remote server.
These mapping should be persistent.
So far so good, except that when the app close, the user can't see the drives the app just mapped.

After some research (https://serverfault.com/a/185885/147818), I understand that when the user logs in, it's session receive 2 tokens, one with low privileges, the other with full privileges, the one that is used to run process when elevation is required.

My question : Is that possible that my app launch a thread that gets the current user filtered token in way a that when the app's tasks are finished, the user can see the network drives in the explorer ?

Is that possible to impersonate the thread with this token ?

I'm aware of these possible workaround :

- Redesigning the app so that only some specific tasks that do requires elevation would be encapsulated in a COM object.
- Tweaking the registry with the `EnableLinkedConnections` setting (requires a user's session restart)

but for some reasons, none of these solutions is an option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The first so called workaround that you reject doesn't look like a workaround. That looks like how you are supposed to do it.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but can you answer to my question ?

Comment: And you don't need COM. You just need two processes. One elevated, the other not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We encountered the same problem when mapping drives from our elevated installer.

The way we handled this is that we first map the drives from the installer which is of course running in the **elevated** UAC state. The last thing the installer does is creates a text file that lists the drive letters and their mapped network drives. Then we run a second program **non-elevated** that does the mapping for the user. These mappings are persistent.

This has worked for us over thousands of installs world-wide on customers' machines.

Comment: thnaks for your answer. The thing is that we should only have to distribute only 1 exe file. Other thing is : Do yo run the second program from the elevated one ?

Comment: I just went out and read our code. I was mistaken.  We run one .exe as non-Admin to read a list of the currently mapped drives that the user has mapped manually. Then we run our admin level exe and re-map them.   But your solution would be similar: have one process elevated and one not. You'll have to figure out how to package them so you can ship as one exe (perhaps zipped or in an installer themselves?) and run them so that they have the right UAC level. This whole approach sounds a bit convoluted, I know, but once you have it working it will work fine.

Comment: You don't need separate executables. You can have one executable that simply runs a second copy of itself when needed, passing it command-line parameters or whatever so it knows that it is a secondary process for a specific task. This is how I deal with UAC elevation without using COM.  I let my apps run UNELEVATED as much as possible (requestedElevationLevel=asInvoker), and then use `ShellExecute/Ex()` with the `"runas"` verb to run ELEVATED copies of themselves only when needed.

Comment: I modified the app so it don't needs anymore to run elevated.
For each task that could need admin right, I relaunch the app itself with params as Remy suggested.

Thanks guys